# After making targetSdkVersion 27 getting BaseDexClassLoader.java:56

Tags: android, android-multidex

My targetSdkVersion was 23, when I make 27 my live app reports 1000 of crashes with   BaseDexClassLoader.java:56. when I revert back to targetSdkVersion 23 no crashes reported.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3343)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20 (ActivityThread.java)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1726)
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
>    at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
>    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:380)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3338)

My app.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven() { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.text"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            multiDexEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
}
dependencies {
    api 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'
    api project(':multipicker')
    api project(':fonts')
    api 'com.github.mancj:SlideUp-Android:2.2.7.1'
    api('com.github.worker8:tourguide:1.0.17-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    api project(':library')
    api 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.28.2'
    api 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.28.2.0'
    api 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    api 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.5'
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    api project(':template-libraryversion2')
    api 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    api supportDependencies.appCompat
    api supportDependencies.design
    api supportDependencies.cardview

    //fcm
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
    api 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //fcm end
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: please provide your app's build.gradle file

Comment: @TibiG I posted app build.gradle, please check

Comment: Are you using something that is specific to "buildToolsVersion '28.0.1' "? If not, you can remove that line. I think that should do the trick for you. This usually happens when using different versions of support libs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as u told I removed "buildToolsVersion '28.0.1' ", but still getting same error ClassNotFoundException BaseDexClassLoader.java:56. And also I am using same support libs 27.1.1. Appreciate ur help.

Comment: I've struggled with this too, so I've decided to use 27.0.2 and it worked

Comment: I tried to use buildTool 27.0.2 but it's says 'The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.4.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.'

Comment: Doc says: _Caution: Do not execute MultiDex.install() or any other code through reflection or JNI before MultiDex.install() is complete. Multidex tracing will not follow those calls, causing ClassNotFoundException or verify errors due to a bad class partition between DEX files_ How to make sure that something is executing before MultiDex.install()